# Using index of a value to loop through a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing

I have a Connect4 board on a list of lists, like this:

```
    currentgame =[["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"], ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]]
```

I'm trying to run a horizontal victory check, whereby I would check whether an index has a value of either X or O, record the index of that value, jump to the next column and check the corresponding space.

```
    rowwinO = 0
    rowwinX = 0
    for column in range(0, 7, 1):
        for row in range(0, 6, 1):              
            if currentgame[column][row] == "X":
                row += 1
                column += 1
                rowwinX += 1
                rowwinO = 0
                if rowwinX == 4:
                    winner = True
                    print("Player 1 Wins! Congratulations")
            elif currentgame[columnrun][row] == "O":
                row +=1
                column += 1
                rowwinO +=1
                rowwinX = 0
                if rowwinO == 4:
                    winner = True
                    print("Player 2 Wins! Congratulations!")
            else:
                row += 1
                rowwinX = 0
                rowwinO = 0
```

The code obviously doesn't work...Would appreciate any help - I'm still not sure if it's actually possible to interrupt and mess with the for loop in such way. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you increment `row` and `column` inside, it has no impact

Comment: to break the loops when you have identified a winner you can use `break`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approch which creates strings from row and cols and then checks wether `XXX` or `OOO` is in these strings.

```
# horizontal
for l in cgame:
    if 'XXX' in ''.join(l):
        print("Player 1 Wins! Congratulations")
        break
    elif 'OOO' in ''.join(l):
        print("Player 2 Wins! Congratulations")
        break

# vertical
for i in range(len(cgame[0])):
    cCol = [j[i] for j in cgame]
    if 'XXX' in ''.join(cCol):
        print("Player 1 Wins! Congratulations")
        break
    elif 'OOO' in ''.join(cCol):
        print("Player 2 Wins! Congratulations")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely looks useful. although i guess would be difficult to use once the values are not strings

Comment: @JuozapasBagdonas what will the values be?